# How to re-enable touchscreen on Windows 10 laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga)?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, thinkpad, touchscreen, device-manager

Couple of months back, my laptop was giving me the annoying "ghost touch" problem with my touchscreen, and not knowing how to fix it, I disabled my touchscreen via device manager.

After a recent Lenovo driver update (I think), the ghost has returned even without an enabled touchscreen, so I'd rather have my touchscreen reinstalled, at least so I can fix the ghost touch problem by calibrating my touchscreen.

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this via device manager any longer. There are several copies of the same device (HID-compliant touchscreen) in device manager, some of which are enabled and some of which are disabled. And the disabled ones say "Currently, this hardware device isn't connected to the computer (Code 45)", instead of having an "Enable" button.

Is there any way I can re-enable my touchscreen? I need to re-calibrate it to fix the ghost touch once and for all -- plus, even my pen (which I really need) hasn't been working right since I disabled it.

Comment: There are new drivers on Lenovo website for [monitor and graphics](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/it/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-yoga-series-laptops/thinkpad-yoga-370/downloads). Perhaps installing them could fix the issue.

Comment: How is touchscreen *monitor and graphics*? In any case, I installed all of Lenovo's recommended drivers for my device before posting here. Doesn't work.

Comment: Lenovo instructions about enabling and disabling [touchscreen](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/HT502617)

Answer (score 1):

Open Device Manager, click Action – Scan for hardware changes.

Besides, you can right click HID-compliant touch screen and select Update Driver Software and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

Open Device Manager and click on 'View' -> 'Show disabled devices'. 
Now go to 'HID-compliant', re-enable your Touchscreen device.

This should do the trick.